# MySql trigger: syntax error: unexpected 'signal' (identifier)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am stuck on this error from hours, could not understand what's the problem in this code. Please help.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER jwdb.valid_query BEFORE INSERT ON jwdb.app_fd_sw_query
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      IF (LENGTH(IFNULL(new.c_ref_no,'0')) = 0) THEN 
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Ref no can not null';
       END IF;  
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What's the version of your mysql?

Comment: SIGNAL does not work before mysql 5.5

Comment: And you should not have a semicolon after the last end

Comment: And your logic seems to be flawed as well. If c_ref_no is null, then you convert it to the string '0', which has a length. It would be a lot easier to declare the field as not null.

Comment: @Shadow I am using 5.1.73

Comment: @Amir I am upgrading my database to 5.7.19 and I will try after that.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have upgraded my database to 5.6.37 and it is working now, It is correct that SIGNAL works with 5.5 and higher version of mysql also thanks for correction in my login, the correct logic is  (LENGTH(IFNULL(new.c_ref_no,'')) = 0)